# make an array unique and display its repeated child

Tags: php, arrays

```
 array (size=3)
 0 => 
  object(stdClass)[20]
    public 'id' => string '12' (length=2)
    public 'cities' => string 'narayangarh' (length=11)
    public 'c_id' => string '24' (length=2)
    public 'places' => string 'pulchowk' (length=8)
 1 => 
  object(stdClass)[21]
    public 'id' => string '13' (length=2)
    public 'cities' => string 'narayangarh' (length=11)
    public 'c_id' => string '24' (length=2)
    public 'places' => string 'sahidchowk' (length=10)
 2 => 
  object(stdClass)[22]
    public 'id' => string '14' (length=2)
    public 'cities' => string 'narayangarh' (length=11)
    public 'c_id' => string '24' (length=2)
    public 'places' => string ' lionschowk' (length=11)
```

In this array, there is one common `cities` 'narayangarh' with common `'c_id'` which are repeated three times and there are different `'places'` with different `'id'`. How can i get output like:

- narayangarh

  - pulchowk
  - sahidchowk
  - lionschowk

So that 'narayangarh' is parent and 'pulchowk', 'sahidchowk' and 'lionschowk' are children. I cant achieve through normal foreach loop. Is it possible through `array_unique()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets pretend your cities are currently stored in an Array called $a.

1. Create an additional array or map $b
2. Loop through $a
3. Append a->places into b[c_id]->places
4. Your cities are now in variable $b in condensed form

eg.

```
$b = array();
foreach ($a as $city) {
  // If city already is in "$b"
  if ( array_key_exists($city->c_id, $b) ) {
    array_push($b[$city->c_id]->places, $city->places);
  } else {
    $b[$city->c_id] = $city;
    $b[$city->c_id]->places = array($city->places);
  }
}
var_dump($b);
```

---

```
array (size=1)
 0 => 
  object(stdClass)[20]
    public 'id' => string '12' (length=2)
    public 'cities' => string 'narayangarh' (length=11)
    public 'c_id' => string '24' (length=2)
    public 'places' => array (size=3) 
                0=> string 'pulchowk' (length=8)                 
                1=> string 'sahidchowk' (length=10)
                2=> string 'lionschowk' (length=11)
```

Edit: $b[$city] changed to $b[$city->c_id]
      swapped array_key_exists code blocks with else code block

Comment: Its only fetching last array. `lionschowk`. php gives error: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: It makes sense why it is saying that. I've made another fix. Should work now.

Comment: I already fixed after i researched about array_key_exist(). I learned one more new array function. Thank you.